# Parâmetros não estão sendo enviados na URL

Tags: php, javascript, url

Bom dia.
Estou tentando enviar alguns parâmetros pela url para outra página porém apenas um está sendo enviado.

Estou mandando dessa forma:

```
 $('#page-wrapper').load("index.php?page=incluiPedido.php?cotacao=" + idCotacao + "&editar=" +  false + "&itens=" + itens + "");
```

A requisição fica assim:  `http://dominio.localhost.com/incluiPedido.php?=cotacao=3`

Os demais parâmetros não aparecem!!

Comment: tenta tirar o .php do parâmetro page

Comment: Oi! eu tirei, os parâmetros foram certinho porém a página não abriu :/

Comment: Agora na index.php voce pode fazer o include usando seu parâmetro page com .php

Comment: Só o primeiro parâmetro vai com interrogação (?), os outros vão com e comercial (&), provavelmente basta só trocar `?cotacao=` por `&cotacao=`.

Comment: Oi, coloquei como vc disse porém só um parâmetro foi enviado...